# how to make a column containing parent records an output link

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller, outputlink

```
<apex:page standardController="contact" recordSetVar="conList" sidebar="false" >
<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock title="Contacts" >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons>    
            <apex:commandButton action="{!create}" value="New Contact" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conList}" var="con" >
                <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.contact.Edit, con.id)}">
                        Edit 
                    </apex:outputLink>    
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Name" >
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.contact.view, con.id)}"> 
                        {!con.name} 
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!con.phone}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!con.account.name}" onclick="{!}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

I am trying to make the account column an output link in the same way i did for the contact name column. If this is not possible, what is the correct approach?

```
 <apex:column>
     <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.contact.account.view, con.id)}"> 
         {!con.account.name} 
     </apex:outputLink>
 </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close with your solution. I believe the below code should show what you are looking for.

```
<apex:page standardController="contact" recordSetVar="conList" sidebar="false" >
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts" >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>    
            <apex:commandButton action="{!create}" value="New Contact" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="con" >
                <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.contact.Edit, con.id)}">
                        Edit 
                    </apex:outputLink>    
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Name" >
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.contact.view, con.id)}"> 
                        {!con.name} 
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!con.phone}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.account.view, con.AccountId)}"> 
                        {!con.account.name}
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: I am getting a runtime error Invalid parameter for function URLFOR

Comment: Where are you using this code?

Comment: i am using it same as you used in your code

Comment: Sorry, I mean are you using it on a page layout or a related list, or a list view?

Comment: in a page layout

Comment: Are you using that on the contact page layout? If so why do you need a list of contacts?

Comment: I am just trying to learn things on my own and came through this problem , that's it.

Comment: That's fine I just want to know more information so that I can help you.